# How to extract the value of a Datepicker at the click of a button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a date picker that I have made using angular-material, whose code in the component.html file is as follows:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width”>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker> 
</mat-form-field>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="submitDate($event)">Submit</button>
```

And I am trying to display the date in the input field at the click of the “Submit” button. The code in the component.ts file is here:

```
date: string = “”;
formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
  month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
  day = '' + d.getDate(),
  year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) 
    month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) 
    day = '0' + day;

  return [month, day, year].join('-‘);
}
submitDate(event) {
    this.dataDate = this.formatDate(event);
    console.log(this.dataDate);
}
```

However the only output I get is the text “NaN-NaN-NaN”
I don’t understand where I am going wrong. How does one extract the date picker value?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the date that way? You can bind the date through the date attribute.

Comment: The event you are passing to `submitDate()` is the button click, not the date. You would need to pass the reference to the input instead. add `#input` to the input tag and change submitDate($event) to `submitDate(input.value)`

Comment: best way for quick developing app is debug! you can debug your code with chrome  browser easily. ;)